# How to make an animate progress bar with startup animation using css

Tags: css, animation, progress

I am trying to implement an animated progress bar with startup animation.

The problem is that I am using `transform: translateX(-100%);` that make ugly effect - progress bar is outside progress area.

Core:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}

.child {  
    background:black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="child">x</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this ugly effect? Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [CSS position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you need position relative and position absolute.

Then the [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> forwards
>   The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  to{ width: 50%; }
}

.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}

.child {  
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:black;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation: slideInFromLeft 1s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="child">x</div>
</div>
```

Now if you want to animate it using translate you have to add overflow:hidden to the parent element

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}

.child {  
    background:black;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%; 
    transform: translateX(0%);
    animation: slideInFromLeft 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="child">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

---

```
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    /*transform: translateX(-100%);*/
  }
  100% {
    width: 90%;
    /*transform: translateX(0);*/
  }
}

.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.child {  
    background:black;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}
```

---

Using CSS transition and Jquery

---

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="child">x</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.progress {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    background: black;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

---

You can set de progress using this jquery code.

---

```
$(".child").css('width','50%');
```

Comment: It is possible without dynamic property in keyFrames?

Comment: Yes!! I have a example using jquery and css transition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so, but I am looking for a solution without external JQuery, etc...

I would like to implement it in ReactJS